# Proving non degeneracy of symplectic form over the linear symplectic quotient

Tags: linear-algebra, quotient-spaces, symplectic-geometry, bilinear-form, symplectic-linear-algebra

$(V, \omega)$  symplectic vector space a$W \subseteq V$  linear subspace. We define the reduced space $(\bar W , \bar \omega)$ as  $\bar W = W/(W \cap W^\omega)$, equipped with the form $\bar\omega ([v], [w]) := \omega(v, w)$ for all $v, w \in W$.
Prove that $\bar\omega$ is a symplectic form

I have already shown that $\bar \omega$ is well-defined, bilinear,skew-symmetric, but I am unsure on how to prove $\bar \omega$ is non degenerate

**My try:**

Let $[w]\in \ker \bar \omega \iff \bar\omega([w],[v])=0,  \forall [v]\in \bar W$
$\iff \omega(w,v)=0, \forall v \in W$ ...(*)

$\iff w \in \ker \omega $

**I am unsure about (*), can I go from $\forall [v]\in \bar W$ to $\forall v\in W$?
and how do I proceed from here?**

For reference:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here are more steps: fix $[v] \in \bar{W}$, and assume that $\bar{\omega}([v],\cdot) = 0$. We will show that $\omega(v,w) = 0$ for all $w\in W$. To do so, we write $\omega(v,w) = \bar{\omega}([v],[w]) = 0$, by assumption. This means that $v\in W^\omega$. But we had $v\in W$ to begin with (or else $[v]$ would not make sense), so $v\in W\cap W^\omega$ and therefore $[v] = [0]$ by definition of quotient (we have shown that $\ker\bar{\omega} = 0$, i.e., $\bar{\omega}$ is non-degenerate).

Comment: Why can't I just conclude that w=[0] from the non degeneracy of  w? and then [w]=[0]?

Comment: I meant the non degeneracy of $\omega$

Comment: Your notation is inconsistent: if $w$ is a vector in $W$, then $w=[0]$ doesn't make sense. To conclude that a vector is in $\ker \omega$ you'd have to check that it is $\omega$-orthogonal to all vectors in $V$. The thing is that assuming that $\bar{\omega}([v],\cdot) = 0$, we can only show that $v$ is $\omega$-orthogonal to everything in $W$, but there's no control over what happens outside of $W$. The proof works even for degenerate $\omega$.

Comment: More precisely, whether $\omega$ is degenerate or non-degenerate, the kernel of $\omega$ restricted to $W$ is $W\cap W^\omega$, so if you mod that out, you get something non-degenerate on $W/(W\cap W^\omega)$.